# GraphObject.make requires a class function or GoJS class name or name of an object builder, not: ToolTip

Tags: javascript, gojs

My version is gojs-1.7.22 and I am trying to load the sample productionProcess but its retrieving the following error:
**"GraphObject.make requires a class function or GoJS class name or name of an object builder, not: ToolTip".**

I am doing something wrong?

```
// Load libs 
  var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  // for conciseness in defining templates
  myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",  // create a Diagram for the DIV HTML element
    {
      maxSelectionCount: 1, // users can select only one part at a time
      "toolManager.hoverDelay": 10,  // how quickly tooltips are shown
      initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,  // scale to show all of the contents
      "ChangedSelection": onSelectionChanged, // view additional information
    });

  function infoString(obj) {
    var part = obj.part;
    if (part instanceof go.Adornment) part = part.adornedPart;
    var msg = "";
    if (part instanceof go.Link) {
      msg = "";
    } else if (part instanceof go.Node) {
      msg = part.data.text + ":\n\n" + part.data.description;
    }
    return msg;
  }

  var colors = {
    "red": "#be4b15",
    "green": "#52ce60",
    "blue": "#6ea5f8",
    "lightred": "#fd8852",
    "lightblue": "#afd4fe",
    "lightgreen": "#b9e986",
    "pink": "#faadc1",
    "purple": "#d689ff",
    "orange": "#fdb400",
  };

  // A data binding conversion function. Given an name, return the Geometry.
  // If there is only a string, replace it with a Geometry object, which can be shared by multiple Shapes.
  function geoFunc(geoname) {
    var geo = icons[geoname];
    if (typeof geo === "string") {
      geo = icons[geoname] = go.Geometry.parse(geo, true);
    }
    return geo;
  }

  myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, "Spot",
      {
        locationObjectName: 'main',
        locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
        toolTip:
          $("ToolTip",
            $(go.TextBlock, { margin: 4, width: 140 },
              new go.Binding("text", "", infoString).ofObject())
          )
      },
      new go.Binding("location", "pos", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
      // The main element of the Spot panel is a vertical panel housing an optional icon,
      // plus a rectangle that acts as the port
      $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
        $(go.Shape, {
          name: 'icon',
          width: 1, height: 1,
          stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
          fill: colors.blue
        },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color", function (c) { return colors[c]; }),
          new go.Binding("width", "iconWidth"),
          new go.Binding("height", "iconHeight"),
          new go.Binding("geometry", "icon", geoFunc)),
        $(go.Shape, {
          name: 'main',
          width: 40, height: 40,
          margin: new go.Margin(-1, 0, 0, 0),
          portId: "",
          stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
          fill: colors.blue
        },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color", function (c) { return colors[c]; }),
          new go.Binding("width", "portWidth"),
          new go.Binding("height", "portHeight"))
      ),

      $(go.TextBlock, {
        font: "Bold 14px Lato, sans-serif",
        textAlign: "center",
        margin: 3,
        maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
        alignment: go.Spot.TopCenter,
        alignmentFocus: go.Spot.BottomCenter
      },
        new go.Binding("text"))

    );

  // Some links need a custom to or from spot
  function spotConverter(dir) {
    if (dir === "left") return go.Spot.LeftSide;
    if (dir === "right") return go.Spot.RightSide;
    if (dir === "top") return go.Spot.TopSide;
    if (dir === "bottom") return go.Spot.BottomSide;
    if (dir === "rightsingle") return go.Spot.Right;
  }

  myDiagram.linkTemplate =
    $(go.Link, {
      toShortLength: -2,
      fromShortLength: -2,
      layerName: "Background",
      routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
      corner: 15,
      fromSpot: go.Spot.RightSide,
      toSpot: go.Spot.LeftSide
    },
      // make sure links come in from the proper direction and go out appropriately
      new go.Binding("fromSpot", "fromSpot", function (d) { return spotConverter(d); }),
      new go.Binding("toSpot", "toSpot", function (d) { return spotConverter(d); }),

      new go.Binding("points").makeTwoWay(),
      // mark each Shape to get the link geometry with isPanelMain: true
      $(go.Shape, { isPanelMain: true, stroke: colors.lightblue, strokeWidth: 10 },
        new go.Binding("stroke", "color", function (c) { return colors[c]; })),
      $(go.Shape, { isPanelMain: true, stroke: "white", strokeWidth: 3, name: "PIPE", strokeDashArray: [20, 40] })
    );

  myDiagram.model = go.Model.fromJson(document.getElementById("mySavedModel").value);
  loop();  // animate some flow through the pipes
```

I am following the sample described in the following link
https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/blob/master/samples/productionProcess.html

Answer (score 0):

The "ToolTip" builder was added in version 2.0.  Try using the sample from the 1.7 version.